# Can't test the value of an array element but can print it

Tags: php, arrays

I have a large multidimensional array called $position that I've assigned a value for all 70 elements.  I can assign new values to the elements, however when I test the value of the element, the website crashes and starts spewing undefined offset messages.

Here is my assignment which works:

```
            while ($ydis > 0) { 
                $position[$rand1_y-$ydis][$rand1_x] = "EE";
                $ydis--;
        }
```

But here is my test that doesn't:

```
            while ($ydis > 0) { 
                if ($position[$rand1_y-$ydis][$rand1_x] == "E") {
                    $position[$rand1_y-$ydis][$rand1_x] = "EE";
                    $ydis--;
                }
        }
```

Basically I only want to assign "EE" if the element already has an "E" in it.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decrement even if is != "E", otherwise it's going to be an infinite loop.

```
while ($ydis > 0) { 
    if ($position[$rand1_y-$ydis][$rand1_x] == "E") {
        $position[$rand1_y-$ydis][$rand1_x] = "EE";
    }
    $ydis--; // <-- HERE
}
```

Comment: That's what it was.  Just overlooked the decrement.